# how to find out if my card supports infrastructure mode?

Tags: wireless

My android doesn't see AdHoc networks so I cannot share internet to my phone that way.

I heard of making a network in infrastructure mode, and I am wondering how to find out if my card supports it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the command:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master
```

if it gives the following as output, it means it doesn't support infrastructure mode:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

If it gives no output, it supports the infrastructure mode. Also, just remember to change "wlan0" to the actual name of your wireless device. You can get the name using the command `ifconfig` .

Comment: thanks.. :( I guess my card doesn't support it

Comment: I think that some cards may have Infrastucture mode with Mad Wifi Drivers, but you have to compile them and use as modules. With my old card wifi it worked

Answer (score 5):

You can check if your device supports **AP** mode by running `"iw list`" and looking in the '**Supported interface mode**s' section for "**AP**". See: [Wireless Driver Support](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers) for AP support.

This is the [Source](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/RealHotspot#How_To_Test)

Comment: Hmm.. I see `AP` as well as `AP/VLAN` in the list of Supported Interface Modes.  However, trying to set the mode to `master` as per @The Terminator's answer gives error message indicating that it doesn't support infrastructure mode.

Comment: @intuited same here