# How to make an android phone use a wi-fi hotspot created on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, android, hot-spot

I want to know how to enable an android phone to detect the hotspot created under ubuntu so that the phone can use thse internet through it.

I have learnt that Android does not support ad-hoc.I tried changing the setting from ad-hoc to infrastructure..but still did not help..

Any way i can do it? Through the system or any app??

Thanx. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Defining the problem:**

Official android distributions do not **show** ad-hoc networks in the wifi list, but they **are capable** of connecting to them.

**Solving the problem:**

Option 1) Create an infrastructure network instead of ad-hoc, if [your cart supports this mode.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106745/how-to-find-out-if-my-card-supports-infrastructure-mode)

Option 2) Root your device and force it to show ad-hoc networks in the wifi list by altering the network config or installing a custom ROM to it.

Comment: Do you mean that official android distributions are capable of connecting to ad-hoc networks **but only if the device is rooted**?  Or is there a way of connecting to an ad-hoc network using a non-rooted phone that doesn't use the wifi list?