# Airdroid and Kubuntu via Hotspot

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kubuntu, android, hot-spot

I would like to connect my Samsung Galaxy with Android using Airdroid to my Kubuntun 12.04 on a Dell 1510.

I do not use a WiFi at home, but a G3 SIM on my laptop. However I have seen I could create a hotspot and use it to connect with Airdroid.

I have followed instructions on this site and other to create a hotspot on Kubuntu 12.04. It seems to have worked, but Airdroid doesn't see the hotspot when scanning. Something went wrong down the line. Could you provide a step-by-step guide on how to connect Airdroid to Kubuntu via hotspot?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that you have created an **ad hoc** hotspot (access point) in Kubuntu. The problem is Android phones do not support ad hoc APs. See [How to make an Android phone use a WiFi hotspot created on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150016/how-to-make-an-android-phone-use-a-wi-fi-hotspot-created-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Ah, possibly, how do I find out?