# my ubuntu 14.04 doesnt support infrastructure mode . in windows 10 i can create hotspot but not in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, dell, wifi-hardware-switch

my laptop is dell inspiron i5 3543 5th generation
the command 
lspci -nn -d 14e4: shows the following result
 Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

i dont know whether its my hardware problem or it is ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This adapter is supported only by Broadcom proprietary drivers in Linux.

These drivers do not support infrastructure mode.

So there is no solution with this adapter.

Comment: is it my hardware problem? so that i can ask for repair from dell

Comment: It is not a hardware fault. It is the drivers fault. There is nothing to repair. I suggest using USB wireless dongle.

Comment: can i fix this problem? i have very little knowledge about linux ...plz be patient

Comment: No, you can't with this adapter. Unless Broadcom releases some other driver, or some open source driver is developed.

Comment: if i install windows ... can i then create hotspot  from this laptop?

Comment: I do not know. Probably you can, if the adapter supports it on hardware level and the Windows driver does too.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Network in System Settings 
Click on to WiFi.
Click the Use as Hotspot button.
If you are already connected to a wireless network, you will be asked if you want to disconnect from that network.

If it successfully connected then enjoy!!
or else it will be your hardware problem.

Search for appropriate drivers for your configuration.

Comment: And how does this enable infrastructure mode?

Comment: go for the command  "sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master"  if it gives an error  then it doesn't support infrastructure mode.

Comment: So? OP already knows that it does not.

Comment: follow this link : http://askubuntu.com/a/109324/455524